# How to keep a specific kernel version in RHEL/Fedora?

Tags: fedora, rhel, kernel, gnome

On my personal machine, a Fedora 33, I am having a problem with booting the system with the new 5.10 Kernels (my Gnome DE never boots up). I haven't found a solution to the problem and I don't have the time to spend hours on it now, so I just want to keep the last version of 5.9, until I can look into it or some future release just works.

I know I can change `installonly_limit` in `/etc/dnf/dnf.conf` to higher numbers, but I don't want dozens of old kernels stored and not be 100% sure that the one I need will never be deleted.

Is there are way to tell the system that I want that particular version to be stored irrespective of how old it is?

PS. Is sb actually had the same problem with GNOME on Fedora and 5.10 they can also say if they solved it and how :)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming this is an issue with nvidia,kernels above 5.10 do not compile the elder nvidia drivers at least version 460.xx is needed with kernel 5.10 and later.